# Applying image as texture on second cylinder is causing a glitch in three JavaScript

Tags: javascript, three.js

### Problem 1

I applied a video as texture of 1 face of a cylinder in three JavaScript (BackSide) Geometry, it works fine.

I tried applying an image texture to another cylinder( FrontSide ) geometry2
and I end up with a glitch probably caused by poor coding, just started working with three JavaScript few days ago.

I created 2 previews

Preview 1- you will find preview for normal player without backside texture, 1 cylinder geometry. I am trying to apply a texture(backside.png) to perfectly fit the backside of this player 
and I ran into a glitch ( the issue )

Link: http://goo.gl/ZkreSV

Preview2 - you will find source for faulty player where I tried applying a material to another cylinder so that my player will look good when rotated around 
but this is where it goes totally all wrong
the issue: http://goo.gl/EBRoc4

### Problem2

I tried restricting the movement of the player to orbit in only x axis and not Y and z plane when a frontend user drags it with old JavaScript, with no success

#

PROBLEM 1 is solved , i worked on the project all night so i mistakenly switch my width and height , waking up this morning i easily spotted the mistake.
does anyone have an idea, how i can solve problem 2

Comment: sorry i didnt include this fiddle earlier, here is the source code -> http://jsfiddle.net/6so2zuez/2/

Comment: What is the actual problem in problem 1? Is it that you want a texture on the back of the screen? If so, AFAIK it is not possible to have a different texture on the back side and front side of the same object/polygon. Please explain the glitch you are seeing. Both the links look ok to me (and appear the same)

Comment: Also, please fix your fiddle, search google for how to use "three.js in jsfiddle"

Comment: yes sir, @2pha i know its not possible . so i created two polygons , in chrome my second cylinder does not show up atall... basically what im trying to achieve sir , in problem 1 is to create add a texture at the backside of a different cylinder geometry so it will look like there is a texture (http://amazondeals.discount/dp/backside.png) there

Comment: fiddle is now working http://jsfiddle.net/6so2zuez/3/

Comment: Clean up the fiddle by putting the Javascript in the javascript window and give it proper indenting. Too much effort to debug the way it is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6so2zuez/7/      done @2pha

Comment: It still needs cleaning up, still has errors loading a video that does not seem to be used. Why are you creating a canvas for the image instead of just applying the image as a map to the material?

Comment: im a newbie in three js , i have fixed the error with video http://jsfiddle.net/6so2zuez/8/  ... problem 1 is solved, problem 2 is just so that the camera only rotates in x plane and not y nor z.